# Query for posts in 2 taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, loop, query-posts

I am currently using the following code to display a list with links to posts in a specific CPT and taxonomy:

```
  <?php
$custom_terms = get_terms('videoscategory');

foreach(array($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'videoscategory',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $custom_term->slug
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $other_custom_term->slug
    ),

)

     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h1 style="margin-top:10px;">'.$custom_term->name.'</h1>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
        endwhile;
     }
} ?>
```

It's working fine like it should, however I want to only display posts that is in both my taxonomies. What do I have to add to do so?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the other taxonomy? You code doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out!

```
<?php
$custom_terms = get_terms('your_other_category');
$other_custom_terms = get_terms('your_category');

foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
foreach ($other_custom_terms as $other_custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $other_custom_term->slug
    ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'your_other_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h1 style="margin-top:10px;">'.$custom_term->name.'</h1>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
        endwhile;
     }
}
} ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), here's how you would query posts from several taxonomies:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'videoscategory',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $custom_term->slug
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'yourothertaxonomy',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $other_custom_term->slug
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer however I can not get it to work. Ive update my question with the edited code.

Comment: @mygm26 what results do you get? do you get expected results with each taxonomy separately? Check your spelling (for example you have an underscore in one tax name but not the other). Also, what is  the value of `$other_custom_term`? It's not defined right now.

Comment: Hello @dalbaeb when using it separately it works as it should, but when trying to use it together nothing shows. The missing underscore is on purpose. The $other_custom_term is product_category. How can I define it and include it in the foreach loop?

Comment: Well, you are looping over all the terms in `videoscategory` taxonomy, and your `product_category` terms are simply not defined inside that loop. You need to figure out how to have terms from both taxonomies available to the query, which is not a WordPress issue, but rather a general code issue.

Comment: Oh, Ok. I tried defining it with this - `$other_custom_terms = get_terms('product_category');` but Im not sure how to include it in the foreach array

Comment: Do your research. See what `get_terms` returns (`print_r` or `var_dump` functions may come in handy to examine output), and also note that you can supply an array of strings as `terms` parameter in your `tax_query`.

Comment: I've been trying to do research and have been unable to figure it out, that's why I posted the question. But thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: Yes, but now you know what wasn't working. You're only really missing one step: generate array of your second taxonomy terms and feed it into the query.

Comment: ...trying and still cant figure it out